# C++ function template argument deduction

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

I have a class template for the smart pointers of which I want an `operator+()`

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class Foo{};

template<typename T, typename U>
std::unique_ptr<Foo<T,U>> operator+(std::shared_ptr<const Foo<T, U>>, std::shared_ptr<const Foo<T, U>>);
```

I now want the following to work with tempate argument deduction:

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo<T, U>> a, b, c;

auto d = a + b + c;
```

It doesn't of course, because `a` and `b` are pointers to non-const, rather than pointers to const. It also doesn't work because `a + b` is a unique pointer rather than a shared pointer.

Is there an elegant solution to make this deduction work? With an operator, I really don't want to explicitly specify the template arguments. The only sort-of feasible way I see is to overload `operator+` for all permutations of `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` as well as const and non-const, but that's 16 function definitions to write.

Comment: Why do you want that, rather than `*d = *a + *b + *c`? That is, why do you want the semantics of these types to be inconsistent with that of other pointer types?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What does it mean to add two pointers together?  What does that do?  Most likely it's not a simple addition and you should be using a named function instead, which would then give you `auto d = named_function(c, named_function(a, b)`.  That said, I rather have a function that takes the underlying object (`Foo<T, U>`) by reference, then you don't have to worry about const or not, and you call it like `auto d = named_function(*c, named_function(*a, *b)`

Comment: The answer to both these comments is that I had been striving for a clean and convenient interface in a context where `Foo` pretty much always exists in the form of a shared pointer to const. Dereferencing each argument in the sum or chaining named functions simply doesn't look as clean to my eye.

I understand however, that it indeed might cause more confusion than convenience if the addition of two pointers has the exact same semantics as the addition of two values, so I will likely go for a function taking const refs.

Comment: If you're generally working with shared pointers to const, and if new objects are created without much fanfare (such as when evaluating an arithmetic expression), then you might be trying to implement a [flyweight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) or some sort of [copy on write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) object. That's not the sort of thing you should try to do with operator overloading hacks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement a template taking const references to `Foo` and then create another template using arbitary parameters that use this implementation.

The following creates always returns `unique_ptr` containing a default initialized `Foo`.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class Foo{};

template<typename T, typename U>
std::unique_ptr<Foo<T,U>> add_foos(const Foo<T, U>& f1, const Foo<T, U>& f2)
{
    return std::make_unique<Foo<T, U>>();
}

template<typename T, typename U>
auto operator+(T t, U u)
{
    // use the function above here
    return add_foos(*t, *u);
}
```

**Edit:**

Used @NathanOlivers suggestion from the comments: it would be preferrable not to make this apply for operands not related to `Foo`

Comment: This does work and looks very clean, but why is there no ambiguity with your `operator+` and basically any other non-template `operator+` that would also fit that signature?